# Window function throws group by error (pyspark, sql)

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, window-functions

**Environment**
I am using sql in databricks.
**Dataset**
My dataset (table) has information about an elements position in a grid (integer) and pseudonomized client_ids who generated a view event.
The client_ids are not necessarily tracked with each position due to tracking logic or technical issues. Therefore, not every client_id needs to have generated an event with the first position but can for example show first touchpoint with the fifth position.

```
CREATE TABLE scrolldepth (client_id STRING, flowId STRING, inPage_position INT);


INSERT INTO scrolldepth VALUES ("01d0481", "e0c1c1", 1);
INSERT INTO scrolldepth VALUES ("01d0481", "e0c1c1", 2);
INSERT INTO scrolldepth VALUES ("01d0481", "e0c1c1", 3);
INSERT INTO scrolldepth VALUES ("01d0481", "e0c1c1", 4);
INSERT INTO scrolldepth VALUES ("01d0481", "e0c1c1", 5);
INSERT INTO scrolldepth VALUES ("f83ce8141", "17213e2", 1);
INSERT INTO scrolldepth VALUES ("f83ce8141", "17213e2", 2);
INSERT INTO scrolldepth VALUES ("f83ce8141", "17213e2", 3);
INSERT INTO scrolldepth VALUES ("f83ce8141", "17213e2", 4);
INSERT INTO scrolldepth VALUES ("f83ce8141", "17213e2", 5);
INSERT INTO scrolldepth VALUES ("f83ce8141", "17213e2", 6);
INSERT INTO scrolldepth VALUES ("f83ce8141", "17213e2", 7);
INSERT INTO scrolldepth VALUES ("47+99cf4d", "648d4e", 1);
INSERT INTO scrolldepth VALUES ("47+99cf4d", "648d4e", 2);
INSERT INTO scrolldepth VALUES ("47+99cf4d", "648d4e", 3);
INSERT INTO scrolldepth VALUES ("47+99cf4d", "648d4e", 4);
INSERT INTO scrolldepth VALUES ("47+99cf4d", "648d4e", 5);
INSERT INTO scrolldepth VALUES ("47+99cf4d", "648d4e", 6);
INSERT INTO scrolldepth VALUES ("47+99cf4d", "648d4e", 7);
INSERT INTO scrolldepth VALUES ("47+99cf4d", "648d4e", 8);
INSERT INTO scrolldepth VALUES ("47+99cf4d", "648d4e", 9);
INSERT INTO scrolldepth VALUES ("47+99cf4d", "648d4e", 10);
INSERT INTO scrolldepth VALUES ("47+99cf4d", "648d4e", 11);
INSERT INTO scrolldepth VALUES ("47+99cf4d", "648d4e", 12);
INSERT INTO scrolldepth VALUES ("47+99cf4d", "648d4e", 13);
INSERT INTO scrolldepth VALUES ("47+99cf4d", "648d4e", 14);
INSERT INTO scrolldepth VALUES ("47+99cf4d", "648d4e", 15);
INSERT INTO scrolldepth VALUES ("47+99cf4d", "648d4e", 16);
INSERT INTO scrolldepth VALUES ("d9171cad", "634446a3", 1);
INSERT INTO scrolldepth VALUES ("d9171cad", "634446a3", 2);
INSERT INTO scrolldepth VALUES ("d9171cad", "634446a3", 3);
INSERT INTO scrolldepth VALUES ("d9171cad", "634446a3", 4);
INSERT INTO scrolldepth VALUES ("d9171cad", "634446a3", 5);
INSERT INTO scrolldepth VALUES ("d9171cad", "634446a3", 6);
```

**Goal**
I want to check for the scroll depth distribution of users and show this with a percentile (to later only include the 95th percentile for example). So as a first test to achieve this, I try to get the total count of distinct client_ids without splitting into multiple subqueries. See the following query:

**Query**

```
SELECT
  inPage_position 
  ,COUNT(DISTINCT client_id) as clients
  ,COUNT(DISTINCT client_id) OVER (ORDER BY inPage_position range BETWEEN unbounded preceding AND unbounded following) as total_clients
FROM scrolldepth
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

**Error**

> AnalysisException: expression '__auto_generated_subquery_name.`client_id`' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;;

Any idea how I can make this work with the window function?

**Target**

| inPage_position | clients | total_clients |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 | 4 |
| 3 | 4 | 4 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 4 | 4 |
| 6 | 4 | 3 |
| 7 | 4 | 2 |
| 8 | 4 | 1 |
| 9 | 4 | 1 |
| 10 | 4 | 1 |
| 11 | 4 | 1 |
| 12 | 4 | 1 |
| 13 | 4 | 1 |
| 14 | 4 | 1 |
| 15 | 4 | 1 |
| 16 | 4 | 1 |
| 17 | 4 | 1 |

*Additional question: Why do I have less issues with the window function in BigQuery's standard sql compared to databricks?*

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to count the unique uses at a given position and up to a given position.  You can do this using two levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT first_inPage_position,
       COUNT(*) as num_clients,
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY inPage_position) as running_clients
BETWEEN unbounded preceding AND unbounded following) as total_clients
FROM (SELECT client_id, min(inPage_position) as first_inPage_position
      FROM scrolldepth
      GROUP BY client_id
     ) sd
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: in my use case this would not lead to the solution I am afraid. I just added a target state table to make it more clear what I intent to do. Thank you for your support nevertheless! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can put total_clients outside of a sub-query:

```sql
SELECT 
    inPage_position, 
    clients, 
    max(clients) over() as total_clients
FROM ( 
    SELECT
      inPage_position, 
      COUNT(DISTINCT client_id) as clients
    FROM scrolldepth
    GROUP BY 1
    ORDER BY 1
)
```

Comment: Hi mck, thanks for the new proposal. The concern about this is, it assumes all client_ids are recognized from 1:n. In the dataset it might happen, that not all client_ids are recognized with the first position's events (for many possible reasons). 
Though it is a good approximation, it is not providing the indefinite overall distinct count of client_ids.